# Response.seeOthers in Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am migrating an application from Jersey REST to Spring REST. Most of the methods return a `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` objects, which means the method can return different status' based on some logic, like returning `Response.seeOther(some URI)`, `Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED`, etc.

What is the equivalent approach in Spring REST for the same? I know we can use `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)`, etc.. but each method can take only one such annotation. How can that be dynamic?

Is `ResponseEntity` the way to do it? If so, what is the equivalent of `seeOther()` method in `ResponseEntity`?

Comment: There is no equivalent. Construct the `ResponseEntity` with the appropriate status code and headers.

Comment: What about `seeOther()`, is it equivalent to just setting the `Location` header?

Answer (score 2):

For redirecting, You can set location in header and return with HttpStatus.SEE_OTHER.
For example

```
java.net.URI location = new java.net.URI(redirectUrl);
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.setLocation(location);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(httpHeaders, HttpStatus.SEE_OTHER);
```